# Hide overflow for inner g element inside svg element

Tags: html, css, svg

I have following SVG structure

```
<svg class="ps-chart-svg" width="100%" viewBox="0 0 1039 792.4571428571428" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid">
  <g transform="translate(0,0)">
    <g class="focus" style="overflow:hidden" transform="translate(45,30)">
      <path class="line" d="..." fill="none" stroke="black"></path>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

What I would like to do is to clip/hide any overflow which is happening due to path element inside parent g element with class focus.
If I add overflow:hidden to svg then the path is contained inside svg element but instead I want it to be contained inside the inner g element.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fyg9wzg5/)

Comment: @ShrutiKarekal This just hides all inner content of the g element what I want is to hide the overflow protruding out of the g element

Comment: `<g>` elements can never have overflow though. They autosize to their contents. See how you're not setting any height or width (and even if you did those attributes would be ignored).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [clip-path](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/clip-path.html) - "Clip Paths on Groups" example.
You can set any shape to clip content by this method.

Comment: I spent so much time researching how to make overflow work on the svg element itself and wrestling with a second viewBox. This solution is much simpler!